# Multiple symbols within a function call in a static library

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

I need to compile a static library which inherits functions with the same name and these functions are furthermore calling each other.
Is there a way to solve my problem?

Here is the **minimal example**:

**add_outer.c**

```
#include "bridge.h"

int add(int a, int b){
    return add_bridge(a,b);
}
```

**bridge.c**

```
#include "add_inner.h"

int add_bridge(int a, int b){
    return add(a,b);
}
```

**add_inner.c**

```
int add(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

Now my problems:

- I can't change the structure
- I can't modify the code at all
- It needs to be compiled to a static library

  - so i can't cheat using a version-script (->shared library)

Comment: I have troubles understanding your question and get the impression that we are looking at a XY problem ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ). Mabye if you could explain **why** you have all those requirements it would help understanding the goal.

Comment: Maybe you find help with improving your question here [tour], [ask], https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ , https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of compiling them together, write a `.c` file that will

1. `#define add something_else`
2. then *`#include`* the `add_bridge.c` and `add_inner.c`